# JSON in Firefox

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a problem with JSON in Firefox (in browsers with webkit engine, the problem doesn't exist).

My Laravel app, returns JSON:

```
return response()->json(['test' => 'test']);
```

And Firefox has feedback:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

When I call it via AJAX and return the response to console, I receive an `<unavailable>` message instead of JSON - in Chrome, in the console, I receive the proper value...

I also tried to return:

```
$response = array('test' => 'test');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
exit();
```

but with the same effect.

I also noticed, the problem is only in my localhost XAMPP server.

Raw JSON:

```
{"test":"test"}
```

Response headers:

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  18
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Tue, 24 Oct 2017 07:59:35 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.13
X-Powered-By    PHP/7.0.13
```

Request headers:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Host    app.local
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't accept json: `Accept: application/json ` is missing

Comment: @mimo — No. The server-side code isn't checking the Accept header. It is always returning JSON.

Comment: can you show how you are making the request and reading the response?

Comment: Check the response properly if it perhaps starts with a BOM character. Your web server might be eagerly sending it with every UTF response. This will not show up in browser debugging but might break the JSON parsing.